# Menubar does not change colour

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have following simple piece of code:

```
  m_menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
  m_menuBar->SetForegroundColour(*wxRED);
  m_menuBar->SetBackgroundColour(*wxGREEN);
  m_menuBar->SetOwnBackgroundColour(*wxYELLOW);
```

But no matter where I set these colours, my menu bar does not show any of them. So what am I doing wrong or what has to be done to let the menu bar and menus appear in a custom colour?

Thank you :-)

Comment: why do you want this? wxWidgets uses native set of everything wherever possible and I don't think menu bar can change colors easily. It can be done with the menu probably (check the ownerdraw sample), but I don't think you can do that with menu bar.

Comment: @Igor do I have to explain why I want to see some other colours? Can aesthetical reasons be explained? Nevertheless: wxMenu offers these functions, so I expect them to work. When it is not possible: why do these functions exists?

Comment: `wxMenu` might have them, but you are trying to change the `wxMenuBar`. See the difference? Besides you will have to encount for different theming including the so called `dark theme`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately a menu bar is not really a window even if `wxMenuBar` does derive from `wxWindow`. This is confusing, but the relationship between the classes is preserved for compatibility even if it's impossible to implement -- in particular, because there is no way to change the colours of a menu under macOS (or under Linux WMs using application menus), for example, so these `wxWindow`-inherited methods can never work in this class.